# Remote sync repository on Raspberry-PI with no access to repo's git

Tags: git, ssh, cmake, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I am trying to find a way to sync and work with some repository on a Raspberry-PI (R-Pi 4, armv7l GNU... quite newbie with Linux versions and so on, don't hesitate if you need more info).
The board has no internet connection, and even less access to some company repositories (access to company network being restricted to approved machines etc).
I have some code project on the R-Pi that is setup, builds, installs, runs... properly.
Now, I'd like to sync this code with some repo to properly track changes, versions, make releases...

I can connect to the R-PI from my other (windows) PC in SSH (and vice versa), which has access to our company Github, can clone the repo etc... (but cannot build it as it's only planned as a small R-PI tool and not aimed at being cross-compiled etc), and I learnt that you can connect through VS-Code and develop from it etc.
But since the R-PI is not connected to the network, it somehow fails to track it.
I tried different approaches, but so far, nothing really seemed to be more practical than manually "scp" sync the folder from the Windows PC to and from the R-PI...
From my searches, I could maybe clone the repo on my Windows, share it, and mount it on the R-PI, but I never really got it to work until now (installing packages without internet access being quite tedious... +  security issues with folder shares to external hw...)

What I would like is maybe find a way to "outsource" the code at build time, doing like
`cmake -S [try-to-access-folder-from-ssh] -B build`

Would that be possible? or edit the CMakeLists to point the cmake sources to such ssh-accessed location? (like `scp` is doing for copying folders and files with `scp -r raspberryPi@192.168.0.xxx:/home/rpi_folder /D/windows_target_folder`)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you can connect to RPi from Windows via SSH but the Raspberry Pi is not connected to your network? How can that be?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not too sure, I connect my RPi to my PC by ethernet with a known local network config (fixed IP addresses) and can ssh rpi@192.168.0.xxx or vice versa, but this doesn't provide main network access to the RPi afaik?
Maybe that means I could access the company network/repo by "proxy" through my PC?

Comment: @MarkSetchell makes a good point but if you can SSH/Putty to RPi from your Windows machine then you can handle everything through Putty (or something similar).

Alternatively, you could setup an AP on the RPI using hostapd and connect from Windows machine via Wifi that way. Then you would connect via WiFi to RPI access point.